# Creating Services in Vue like Angular

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I developed an api service for one of my resources it looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
get(){
    axios.get('/emails')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return error.response;
        });
    },
    update(){

    }
}
```

My vue template looks like this:

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-7 pt-5 pr-2 pb-5 pl-5">

    {{emails}}


</div>
</template>
<script>
import EmailMessageService from '../../services/EmaiMessageService';
export default  {
   data(){
       return {
           pageNumber: 0,
           emails:[],
       }
   },
   mounted(){
       console.log(EmailMessageService.get())
       this.emails = EmailMessageService.get();
   }
}
</script>
```

When I call this method in my service I get undefined in the component but can console log it out fine in the service. It seems like it could be a scop issue but I am 100% lost on what is going on .

I looked at some . other resources online I could not figure our how to solve this with Axios

Comment: You need to return the axios promise from `get`. Then in `mounted` your code will look something like this: `EmailMessageService.get().then(emails => this.emails = emails)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a promise `then` to handle the response.

I'm not sure how the data is formatted, so you'll likely need additional checking to verify the data is in correct format. You should return the axios promise and handle the returned data using a `then` handler, and it's a good idea to implement catch too

part1:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    get(){
      return axios.get('/emails') // <--- Need this to return the promise
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            throw error.response; // <-- use throw to be able to use catch
        });
    },
    update(){

    }
}
```

part 2:

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-7 pt-5 pr-2 pb-5 pl-5">

    {{emails}}


</div>
</template>
<script>
import EmailMessageService from '../../services/EmaiMessageService';
export default  {
   data(){
       return {
           pageNumber: 0,
           emails:[],
       }
   },
   mounted(){
       EmailMessageService.get()
           .then(response => {
               console.log(response)
               this.emails = response
           })
           .catch(error => {
               // handle error
               console.error(error)
           })
   }
}
</script>
```

---

response to whether you should always have a catch

**TL;DR;**
You should always strive to handle exceptions, at every stage.

There are three layers at work here

- View

  - Your vue component
- Wrapper

  - Wraps and abstracts the request library/function
- Axios/Request(er)

  - the actual request making and handling library

Your request originates from your *View layer*, initiated by some click or during `mount()`, goes to *wrapper layer*, which abstracts the Axios request. Once the Request is made, and the response is received, it travels back from *Axios* to the *wrapper* and then back to your *View*. Each layer is does some error checking.

The *axios* response handler can only tell, using headers and parsing of json, whether the data received back was valid, so you should implement additional error validation at your *wrapper*. You can also add additional logic at this stage that could do a fallback request or notification. But it still needs to tell the view that an error happened. At the *view layer* your error validation would determine what the user sees or what options they are presented with either on success or on failure; this decision cannot be made by the Wrapper nor Axios, as they are not meant to touch the DOM.

if you do not implement a catch at the View Layer, whether the error comes from the *wrapper* or *axios* you will end up with two possible issues during an exception.

1. You don't know if you're resolving an error or a correct response,
2. you may never get a `then()` fired and without a `catch`, you can have the user waiting without any notification.

So, the way I would handle this, is that the user sees a loading spinner by default, somewhere within the `then` function, or a call within, the loading spinner would be replaced with the actual data. if I see a `catch` however, I would use an error message to replace the spinner.

Comment: I have a carch in the service file. Have a catch in both?

Comment: Updated answer. I also noticed something I missed earlier, and that is that your get() function doesn't seem to be returning anything, so I updated the code.